# Proper way to save a DateInterval to Realm

Tags: swift, realm, dateinterval

Realm doesn't support `DateInterval` to be store into the database. For now our team do the following:

```
private let _intervalBegins = List<Date>()
private let _intervalEnds = List<Date>()

var dateIntervals: [DateInterval] {
    get {
        var intervals = [DateInterval]()
        for (i, startDate) in _intervalBegins.enumerated() {
            let endDate = _intervalEnds[i]
            intervals.append(DateInterval(start: startDate, end: endDate))
        }
        return intervals
    }

    set {
        _intervalBegins.removeAll()
        _intervalBegins.append(objectsIn: newValue.compactMap{ $0.start })
        _intervalEnds.removeAll()
        _intervalEnds.append(objectsIn: newValue.compactMap{ $0.end })
    }
}
```

Is there a more "proper" way to do this? Maybe to store both the *start* and *end* dates into one property/database column? And get those value directly without *"parsing"* them with another variable as we do now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you notice, Realm [doesn't support `DateInterval`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet), but Realm is able to save your custom objects. In this case you can create your own `RealmDateInterval` (or so) and create initializer, that allows you to create object from `DateInterval`:

```
dynamic var start: Date = Date()
dynamic var end: Date = Date()

convenience init(dateInterval: DateInterval) {
    self.init()
    self.start = dateInterval.start
    self.end = dateInterval.end
}
```

Next thing, when you retrieve `RealmDateInterval` from Realm you really want `DateInterval` instead. Here you can create a bridge function, that can convert `RealmDateInterval` to `DateInterval` or create a protocol with convert func and 
adopt it to `RealmDateInterval` (i.e. clearly show everybody `RealmDateInterval` has specific functionality).

```
protocol DateIntervalConvertible {
    func toDateInterval() -> DateInterval
}

extension RealmDateInterval: DateIntervalConvertible {

    func toDateInterval() -> DateInterval {
        return DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
    }

}
```